# Gitlab CI: Build Project from another Project/shared pipeline project

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am trying to create shared pipeline(Gitlab CI) for 15 other projects since they have similar functionality.. I am facing a problem of building external project from shared pipeline project folder since it always build the project of current working directory where .gitlab-ci.yml file is present.. Can anybody please suggest me how should I do it?

e.g - Project A is shared and I created .gitlab-ci.yml
- I have 15 other Projects.. lets say one of them is Project B

Project B is already created. I am creating Project A and trying to automate using gitlab. I created .gitlab-ci.yml in project A but it always runs the project where .gitlab-ci.yml is present..

How do I tell gitlab ci to run the project B from Project A?

Comment: You can do this with include statements: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/includes.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to use a private GitLab repo as a remote include in GitLab CI? If so, how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70867747/is-it-possible-to-use-a-private-gitlab-repo-as-a-remote-include-in-gitlab-ci-if)